# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'customer_id'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models in an app called ***customer***. The models are **Customer** and **Account**. The logic is one customer can have many accounts. So the auto generated default 'id' column in **Customer** is Foreign Key in **Account**. **Account** also has an auto generated default 'id' column. I have created a function for an *account_id* field in **Account** which will be generated on a simple algorithm. *customer_id* and *id* from **Account** will be concatenated as 'customer_id'_'id', (for eg. 1_1). The function will first check the current *customer_id* of the **Account** instance created and then check which is the last *id* for that *customer_id*. For newly added account, it will capture the *id* part from *account_id* (i.e. the part after underscore) and increment it by 1. Then concatenation happens for the same *customer_id* and *id*. Following is the code-:

**models.py**

```
from asyncio.windows_events import NULL
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from .utils import set_account_id


class Customer(AbstractBaseUser):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, null=True)
    org_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null = True)
    org_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='logos', blank=True)
    subscription_start_date = models.DateField()
    subscription_end_date = models.DateField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'email']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    account_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, null=True)  
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=[
        ("survey", "SURVEY"), 
        ("sme", "SME"), 
        ("residents", "RESIDENTS")
        ])
    account_subscription_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    account_expiry_date = models.DateField(null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'email']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

def pre_save_set_account_id(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.account_id:
        instance.account_id = set_account_id(instance) #Error here
        print(instance.account_id)

pre_save.connect(pre_save_set_account_id, sender=Account)
```

**utils.py**

```
def set_account_id(instance):
    Klass = instance.__class__

    fk = 'customer_id'
    obj = Klass.objects.first()
    field_object = Klass._meta.get_field(fk)
    fk_value = field_object.value_from_object(obj) #Error here

    last_account = Klass.objects.filter(customer_id=fk_value).all().order_by('id').last()
    accounts_pk = last_account.id 
    new_account_int = accounts_pk + 1
    new_account_id = fk_value + '_' + new_account_int

    return new_account_id
```

Now when I have entered one record in **customer** and trying to enter a record in **account** through the admin panel. When I am filling out the form for **account** in admin panel, I am leaving the *account_id* as blank. After clicking on **Save**, I am getting the following error-:

AttributeError at /admin/customer/account/add/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'customer_id'

I have commented "Error here" on the specific lines at which the the error was pointed out by Django debugger. I am new to Django and have tried a lot but couldn't resolve the error. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey i don't know why you need this account_id as db field in first place? If you need it to perform filter, I suggest to use post_save signal like:

```
def post_save_set_account_id(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.account_id is None:
        instance.account_id = f'{instance.customer.id}_{instance.id}'
        instance.save()
```

But if you don't need to build sql query based on account_id field i suggest use @property in Account model:

```
@property
def account_id(self):
    return f'{self.id}_{self.account.id}'
```

then you cen use it as model field for example:

```
account = Account.objects.get(pk=1)
account.account_id
```

prints for example:

```
1_1
```